# Distinct CONTACT_ID from ContactsContract.Data

Tags: android, sql, distinct, android-contacts, contactscontract

I need to make a query to `ContactsContract.Data` table and values in `CONTACT_ID` column would be different (distinct).

Code:

```
final Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
final String[] projection = new String[] {//
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, //
    ContactsContract.Data._ID, //
    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,//
    ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY //
};
final StringBuilder selectionBuilder = new StringBuilder();
selectionBuilder.append(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID);
selectionBuilder.append("= ? AND ");
selectionBuilder.append(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE);
selectionBuilder.append("= ? ");
final String selection = selectionBuilder.toString();
final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {//
    String.valueOf(groupId), //
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE //
};
return context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

First of all, I've tried to add "`DISTINCT` " to `ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID` in projection. But there was an exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column DISTINCT contact_id`

Then, I write this way:

```
"'DISTINCT "+ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID+"'".
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column 'DISTINCT contact_id'
```

Then, I add to selectionBuilder:

```
selectionBuilder.append(" GROUP BY ").append(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);
```

Once again, an exception:  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error: , while compiling: `SELECT contact_id, _id, display_name, lookup FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1) AND (data1= ? AND mimetype= ?  GROUP BY contact_id) ORDER BY display_name ASC`

At last, I've append "group by" statement right after sortOrder, but:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT contact_id, _id, display_name, lookup FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1) AND (data1= ? AND mimetype= ? ) ORDER BY display_name ASC GROUP BY contact_id
```

Is it ever possible to make query with distinct?
Maybe, I should append something to URI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are targeting devices below ICS, you can use the GROUP_BY clause by adding a `)` before the group by and a `(` after:

```
selectionBuilder.append(") GROUP BY (")
```

As of ICS and above, the query interpretor is smarter and closes any unclosed parenthesis to prevent injection.

However, I don't see why you need distinct contact_ids here. A contact should probably have only one Data to make the association with one group, so you probably receive a different contact on each line.

Also, there may be something to do with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_GROUP_URI it is not documented, but given its position, it may well be a direct access to Contacts belonging to a Group. You would use that Uri :

```
Uri uri = ContentUri.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_GROUP_URI, groupId);
```

And then query it like the Contacts.CONTENT_URI

Comment: Yes, I've found your question and your searches for injection of GROUP BY. I've found it very interesting :) Too pity it's a hack and it was blocked :)
However, I seek common decision, not only for GroupMembership. It must be also ported to CommonDataKinds.Phone - I know about its CONTENT_FILTER_URI, but my customer want to filter by ANY portion of phone numbers.

Comment: I liked you answer, but I want to open bounty, cause this question didn't receive enough attention. Maybe, your answer would be the best.